# nodejs crypto hmac produces different hashes if secret is passed as a literal vs variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, node-webkit, hmac

I'm trying to use nodejs' createHmac function from its crypto library.

Problem: It produces different hashes when given (seemingly) identical arguments. The only difference being whether the 'secret' parameter is a string variable, or a string literal.

The following SPA isolates the issue. I'm using nwjs (node webkit) SDK flavour v 0.14.2 to run this code on OS X El Cap.

Any help and advice gratefully received.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Context Menu</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

<div id="wrapper">
</div>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   
    integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var nodeCrypto = require('crypto');

var payload = 'twas brillig and the slithy toves did gyre and gimble in the wabe';

//
// simple UI to get a user-entered secret
// and echo the results.
// enter 'wibble' in input element to demo the problem to match hard coded literal
//
$('#wrapper').append (
    $('<div>').addClass('form-group')
        .append (
            $('<label>').attr('for','userinput').text('Tell me a secret:'),
            $('<input>').addClass('form-control').attr('type','text').attr('id','userinput')
        ),
    $('<p>').attr('id', 'hash'),
    $('<p>').attr('id', 'nash')
);

$('input').on('change', function (ev) {

    // compute hash based on user input
    var hash = nodeCrypto.createHmac ('sha256', $(this).val())
        .update (payload)
        .digest ('hex');            
    console.log ('hash: ' + hash);
    $('p[id=hash]').text('secret: ' + $(this).val() + ', hash: ' + hash);
    // logs hash: f7b4ae1aaa35b813571f00bca7c81d08176b56cb3a1d1f8c8ba95a17ba6f6f29
    // as long as user enters 'wibble'

    // compute hash based on string literal
    var nash = nodeCrypto.createHmac ('sha256', 'wibble')
                .update (payload)
                .digest ('hex');            
    console.log ('nash: ' + nash);
    $('p[id=nash]').text('secret: wibble, hash: ' + nash);
    // logs hash: c9592948b3de038c9aa339f94b61928de803417183a6c95b1829a04c69fe6bf6

});
```

**Screengrab**
[Shows user input together with computed hashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnBIH.png)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hmac",
  "main": "index.html",
  "description": "nodejs crypto hmac test",
  "author": "xxx"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's something about the discipline of isolating a problem and writing an explanation for the tough but fair crowd that is stackoverflow that often seems to shake out a solution all by itself.

So with apologies for this 'asked & answered'. I'm just relieved to have a solution.

A little bit of further experimentation yielded these insights:

1. forcing the argument to be a separate object via

> secret = new String(...)

caused a failure inside of node's crypto library:

> TypeError: not a buffer.

This is a clue!

2. after converting the user input to a Buffer before passing it as the secret to createHmac results in consistent behaviour between the 2 calls.

**Updated js**

```
// compute hash based on user input
    var secretStr = $(this).val();
    var hash = nodeCrypto.createHmac ('sha256', secretStr)
        .update (payload)
        .digest ('hex');            
    console.log ('hash: ' + hash);
    $('p[id=hash]').text('secret: ' + $(this).val() + ', hash: ' + hash);
    // logs hash: f7b4ae1aaa35b813571f00bca7c81d08176b56cb3a1d1f8c8ba95a17ba6f6f29
    // as long as user enters 'wibble'

    // compute hash based on string literal
    var nash = nodeCrypto.createHmac ('sha256', 'wibble')
        .update (payload)
        .digest ('hex');            
    console.log ('nash: ' + nash);
    $('p[id=nash]').text('secret: wibble, nash: ' + nash);
    // logs nash: c9592948b3de038c9aa339f94b61928de803417183a6c95b1829a04c69fe6bf6

    // compute hash based on Buffer initialised from user input
    var secretBuf = Buffer.from($(this).val());
    var mash = nodeCrypto.createHmac ('sha256', secretBuf)
        .update (payload)
        .digest ('hex');            
    console.log ('nash: ' + nash);
    $('p[id=mash]').text('secret: wibble, mash: ' + nash);
    // logs mash: c9592948b3de038c9aa339f94b61928de803417183a6c95b1829a04c69fe6bf6
```